# How to allow more than 16 users to connect to TP-Link router

Tags: router

I have a TP-Link WR841N at my small office; between the PCs, laptops and phones we have more than 16 devices but none of them are on heavy load. But, once the amount of users gets to 16, the router seems to stop assigning or letting any devices connect. Is there any way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly happens? Are new devices unable to obtain an IP address? If so, what size is the DHCP pool set to?

Comment: so when i connect it just stops connecting, on the phones it would say saved but not connected, the dhcp pool is 100-199 so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You could try setting up a different DHCP server on the network and disabling the one on the router.

Comment: So are you perhaps referring to WiFi?

Comment: oh yeah sorry i am referring to strictly wifi

Comment: Late to the table but this model of router does have a limit on the number of connections - and it's around 16. I've never determined whether this is a limit on Wi-Fi or includes wired. I suspect Wi- Fi. The limitation is probably there due to limited CPU and RAM in the router's firmware

Answer (score 2):

If we’re talking about WiFi, it could simply be a (albeit silly) firmware limitation.

I’ve been running two WR841ND (same thing with detachable antennas) with OpenWrt (linked via WDS) for over a year now, and they never once crashed or otherwise failed to provide WiFi coverage. So you might want to give it a shot, if you feel up to it.

[Installation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd#installation) is dead simple: Just upload it as a firmware update and wait. But please make sure you read all the relevant content on the OpenWrt wiki page.

Since these things are so cheap, you might want to buy another one just to try it.

Comment: Yes, it's most certainly a limitation of the software - I don't think the wireless chipset in these devices has a limit. At the end of the day, a router is simply a small computer running a software program and using RAM. The CPU isn't very fast and it probably doesn't have much memory. Other router operating systems could very well use memory more efficiently and the software is optimised - allowing more concurrent connections. I'm currently looking at RouterOS on the Mikrotik devices which are very powerful

Answer (score 1):

How old is the router? they supposed allow 256 concurrent connections. Maybe somebody changed the DHCP server RANGE setting in the router home page?

Or maybe you need to check if you locked out any mac addresses in the router settings...

Was a cheap router over a year old? Then through it out and buy a new one..

Comment: 256 concurrent connections aren't the same as 256 different IPs. Most PCs will use multiple connections anyway, because you have many apps and many webpages running on the PC, each uses multiple sockets to connect to the server. I'd say a single computer can have 200 sockets easily

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this before as a DHCP max array size issue. Try using static IPs, and/or disabling DHCP.

DHCP is a mechanism by which the router gives new IP addresses to machines that try to connect to it. I figure that DHCP uses its own table in the routers memory to store which machines have which IPs. What I've seen before, and I can't explain completely the works on this, is that some routers will have a hard limit on the number of machines they can handle before they start misbehaving.

I've experienced this before and solved it by trying to keep the number of machines to a minimum, or by sparing the router the trouble of using DHCP to manage IPs and just giving out IPs manually. Go to your network's configuration in your operating system, and type an internal IP there, usually something like 192.1.168.x (make x something between 2-253, or to be safe, something between 100-200, so you know which are yours).

But then you have to worry about stuff like IP collision. Different machines cannot have the the same IP address.

note: I only expanded this answer on request. If it doesn't work for you, I may delete it.

other note: that "DHCP range" answer seems really worthwhile.

Comment: Can you give more info on how to do this? Currently, the answer is very low quality, and may not help future visitors.

Answer (score -2):

yeah yeah had the same problem just reboot the router it should be fine I got about 25 iot connected 5 phones 6 pc  plus 3 voip